# Comment system notifications

Tags: support, comments, notifications

I found a ridiculous bug for the comments notification system. If I comment on someone else's question thread, I'm notified of any reply to the particular answer or question I've commented on. However, if I commented on **my own** question thread, I'm not notified of any comment activity at all. It's extremely annoying that I've to go check each and every question I asked just to review if there's been any activity.

**EDIT**
The problem is more localized than I thought. In the couple of questions I posted on Ask Ubuntu today, I was notified of the comments to the question, but I missed the notifications of comments in the answers I received even though I commented on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is correct.

You are notified when:

- someone answers your question
- someone comments on your question or answer
- someone types @yourname in a comment below yours

Note that users with 1 reputation can always comment on *their* posts, questions, and answers to their questions.

see: https://askubuntu.com/faq for more details.

Comment: You're not completely right there. I do get notification when someone answers my question, but I never got notifications of comments in my question threads - I got multiple replies just yesterday one of my questions, and I can show you the screen shot of my notification without a single mention of that question. And finally, I don't know about `@yourname` feature since I received notification of comments on someone's question/answer regardless of my name being mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure about the comments for new users, but I read quite a few times of users resorting to use the answer feature because they couldn't comment.

Comment: @toki we wrote the software you are using right now, so what I specified is correct. If new users do not register and lose their identity cookie, it's possible they might not be able to comment on their own posts -- but that's hardly our fault.

Comment: Okay, my bad about the new users thing, but I'm still very much troubled about the notifications I miss.

Comment: Okay, the problem is more specific than I thought before. I was notified of comments on my question but not the comments on the answer I received. I will update my question here. Interestingly, I was notified the comments you made in Ubuntu META. Can you verify the notifications I received from the logs or something?

Comment: @toki you would not be notified of comments on an answer to your question, unless those comments replied to an earlier comment of yours. See rules 1-3 above..

Comment: But it is a fact that I had an earlier comment. Take a look at this answer for example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/27061/install-restricted-drivers-in-command-line I did not receive a single notification about it except for notifying me that this answer was posted.

Comment: all correct. Unless they do @toki ***AS I JUST DID*** you won't see the comment, because they were not commenting on YOUR post.

Comment: @Jeff, I apologize for you to have to deal with a stubborn mule such as myself. May I request an option to receive notifications for anything as long as I commented?